# Are Percentage Widths Allowed in CSS (and CSS3 specifically)?

Tags: html, css

As I understand it, percentage widths are not suported in **HTML5**. Widths and suchlike have to be specified in pixels. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

However, am I allowed to create an element in CSS, specify its width as a percentage, and then use that element on an HTML5 page? (I've tried it, and it does what I want it to do, but is it best practice?)

---

Although this was intended as generic sort of question, the specific thing I was trying to implement was a `<table>` element:

```
<table class="wideTable">
```

And the CSS would then look like this:

```
table.wideTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

Thank you very much to Daniel Beck for his wonderfully thorough answer. It seems that **Percentage widths in CSS are fully supported**.

Comment: `percentage widths are not suported in HTML5.`--> any reference for this? as a side note width is defined in the CSS spec unless you are talking about the width attribute (which is another story)

Comment: Please show your CSS and HTML so we can see exactly what you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> percentage widths are not suported in HTML5

I suspect what you're referring to here are the HTML `width` and `height` attributes:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

You are correct that [those values are in pixels](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#sec-dimension-attributes); the spec says these attributes "must have values that are valid non-negative integers", so it would not be correct to use values such as "100px" or use other units (such as percentage) in those attributes.

(Browsers vary in how they handle incorrect units in these attributes, depending on the unit, and often differently for width versus height. it's kind of a mess, don't wade into it.)

The width and height attributes are only valid for certain elements, though: images, video, iframes, etc.

> am I allowed to create an element in CSS, specify its width as a percentage, and then use that element on an HTML5 page?

Absolutely, yes!   This can be done in external CSS, or inline in the HTML using the `style` attribute, not the `width` or `height` attributes; and can apply to any element that has any display dimensions (so not `<br>` for example).

If used on the same element, style attributes will override CSS, which will in turn override the "width" and "height" attributes:

```css
.override {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100" class="override">
```

Comment: but you didn't specify `px` unit .. you probably mean that they will get interpreted as pixel values.

Comment: What? The width and height attributes don't take a unit, they are always in pixels.  See the spec I linked to: "The attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers."

Comment: that's what I meant, you don't specify any unit because they will be considered as pixel ... we don't explicitely specify them as pixel value using `100px` for example. They are implicitely evaluated as pixel.

Comment: I changed the wording of the answer to make it clear that the units should be omitted from those attributes.

Answer (score 1):

"Please correct me if I'm wrong" -> You are wrong.

Percentage values for widths are commonly used.

Comment: [The specs that Daniel Beck mentions](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#sec-dimension-attributes) seem to disagree with you.

Comment: You asked about CSS, which my answer is about. Daniel Beck writes about HTML attributes (i.e. attributes inside HTML tags which are not `style`attributes, i.e. not inline CSS).

Comment: P.S.: I should a´have added a ";-)" after "You are wrong" - i didn't mean that in a negative way - sorry if you perceived it that way.

Comment: I mean... "percentage widths are not supported in HTML5" is a true statement, unless you consider CSS to be part of HTML5.  Which it sort of is? but not really? Hooray, all of us are correct! ;-)